# What projection is this? Is it van der Griten?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, map-maker

I am trying to convert some maps that came in `.dra` format from [MapMaker](https://mapmaker.com/v4/Map%20maker%204.Pro.htm) to shapefiles. My problem is that the original files have no projection information, which complicates their use after exporting them using MapMaker. The map of the original data looks like this:

[image: this]

...which looks very similar to the `van der Grinten` projection, as can be seen here:

[image: here]

I also compared it to `Robinson` but that one does not look that similar. Neither does `Eckert II`.

One major complication is that the units of the original map do not seem to be meters, but some multiple. Specifically, if I import the world map from natural earth and compare bounds with the bounds of the exported shapefile I get different multiples, so it is not clear which unit it really is. Here's some `python` code that shows the issue

```py
import geopandas as gp

# Import World shapefile from Natural Earth in WGS84
world_wgs84 = gp.read_file('https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip')
world_wgs84 = world_wgs84.loc[world_wgs84.NAME.str.find('Antar')==-1].reset_index(drop=True)
world_wgs84.plot()

# Import MapMaker shapefile
mapmaker_shp = gp.read_file('https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxuoqh8msn9184o/8000.zip?dl=1')
mapmaker_shp.plot()

# Project to van der Grinten for comparison
world_vdg = world_wgs84.to_crs('ESRI:54029')
world_vdg.plot()

# compare bounds
wb = world_vdg.total_bounds # array([-19917658.38747369,  -8308978.01939191,  19974342.14947391, 14122774.74128915])
mb = mapmaker_shp.total_bounds # array([-9053.47050001, -4725.776     , 11509.66949999,  7034.509     ])
wb / mb # array([2200.00257221, 1758.2251083 , 1735.44011403, 2007.64186118])
```

If I define the `van der Grinten` projection and use different units, e.g., 1600 meters, the maps are more similar and they overlap quite closely, but not exactly as if the units in the x and y direction are different.

```py
# Define Van der Grinten
vanDerGrinten = 'PROJCS["World_Van_der_Grinten_I", GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", DATUM["WGS_1984", SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], PROJECTION["VanDerGrinten"], PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], UNIT["Meter",1600], AUTHORITY["EPSG","54029"]]'

world_vdg1600 = world_wgs84.to_crs(vanDerGrinten)
ax = world_vdg1600.plot(); mapmaker_shp.plot(ax=ax, color='r')
```

as shown here:

[image: here].

So the questions are

- whether this is really the `van der Griten` projection and if so how can I transform this into WGS84 correctly
- if it is not `van der Griten` then which projection is it?

Comment: I'd reconsider the use of your tags. This question seems to be purely about projection and not the use of e.g. ArcGIS, geopandas

Comment: While not the use itself, I'd like help with implementation in any of these if it is not a straightforward thing.